# How to find the set X?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am given $2$ sets $A$ and $B$ :

$A = \{1,2,5,6,7\}, B=\{0,4,6,7,9\}$

and two more sets $C = \{0,1,2,6,7,9\}$ and $M = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

I have the following set equation to be solved:

$(A \cap X) \cup (B \cap X^c) = C$

My own thoughts have been to use the law of inverse : $X \cup X^c  = \emptyset$.

But I can't use the distributive law for sets stated below:

$A \cup (A \cap B) = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$

When $X \subseteq M$. So how can I find the X that satisfies $(A \cap X) \cup (B \cap X^c) = C$?

Comment: Tell us what the set $C$ is

Comment: @FShrike Thanks i forgot to add set C!

Comment: Just tidied up your MathJax and grammar a little. The post looks much better now, and should receive better attention. I would suggest that you edit in the name of your textbook, or wherever you're reading set theory from, so that others can use it as a reference for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint to get started: something is in $C$ iff it's in $A$ and $X$, or in $B$ and not $X$. Since $0$ is in $C$, that means it's in $A$ and $X$ or else it's in $B$ and not in $X$. But it's not in $A$; what does that tell you about whether $0 \in X$?

Comment: Thanks! I had to think little but thanks your answer helped me and 0 belongs to the subset X!